# Are all compact and connected sets $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ also path connected?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

If $\varnothing\neq K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ (for any $n\geq 1$) is both compact and connected, is it then also necessarily path-connected? I have not seen this result in my basic real analysis text which lead me to believe that the claim is not true, but I have been unable to both produce or find suitable counterexample.

Comment: Well known counter-example:  $\{(x,\sin (\frac 1 x): 0 < x \leq 1\} \cup \{(0,y): -1\leq y\leq 1\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Take the graph of (bounded) topologist's sine curve: $x\mapsto \sin(1/x)$ for $x\in(0,1]$. And then its closure (which just adds the vertical $\{0\}\times [-1,1]$ line).